# Are there better rates for scraping services?

Tags: web-scraping

I know scrapers have to use bandwidth, so that has to figure in...and thus the per-page/request rates, but is the below a good rate?

$25/mth = 100K pages ($0.00025 / page)

$50/mth = 250K pages ($0.0002 / page)

$75/mth = 500K pages ($0.00015 / page)

$100/mth = 1M pages ($0.0001 / page)

$200/mth = 5M pages ($0.00004 / page)

$300/mth = 10M pages ($0.00003 / page)

Mozenda seems to be much pricier than that...is there better? Is the above competitive? Over-priced?

Comment: Don't know if this is any use to you. But you could also just download some webcrawling bot and do the data collection yourself ...from there to extracting useful stuff from the content you download ..that's another story.

Comment: An interesting question, but not appropriate to the "My code isn't working" mission statement of StackOverflow. This *might* be more appropriate for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ . You can use the  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630777/are-there-better-rates-for-scraping-services# flag link at the bottom of your question and ask for a moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, your are right shellter, about the nature of the question not being one which helps coders, etc. Thank you for the reference to  webmasters.stackexchange.com. Thanks Robert, but it must be offloaded to a third party, so just trying to understand HOW to evaluate a fair rate. Thanks both of you.